# traducir "facility" (eufemismo para "cárcel")

Tags: traducción, vocabulario, solicitud-de-término, eufemismos

Necesito un eufemismo para *cárcel*.  En inglés se usa *facility*.

Creo que se prefiere usar un eufemismo para no ofender.

Comment: Quizá si incluyeses en la pregunta la frase o parte de la frase que intentas traducir, podrías obtener mejores respuestas (más específicas). Además, no lo indicas, pero viendo los comentarios buscas una palabra que esté mínimamente asociada con "cárcel" pero que usada en tu texto, donde queda claro en contexto, se va a referir a la cárcel, no?

Comment: @Diego  ---  ¡Sí!

Answer (score 6):

Dependiendo del contexto, tal vez puedas ahorrarte los calificativos que aparecen en las propuestas de las otras respuestas y escribir, simplemente, *centro*. Ese contexto ya debería indicar claramente a qué tipo de centro te refieres.

Por si te sirve de ayuda, en España es habitual llamar *internos* a los presos cuando el contexto deja claro a qué te estás refiriendo. Ya sé que preguntas por el lugar, no por las personas que hay en él, pero a lo mejor te vale para algo.

Comment: "Centro" a secas me parece algo ambiguo si no se le añade suficiente contexto.

Comment: @fedorqui Desde luego. Pero *facility* en inglés también necesita contexto; cualquier instalación es una *facility*. Como no sé qué información adicional puede tener el oyente en este caso, no sé si mi propuesta funcionaría o no. Que yo sepa, en español no tenemos una palabra para este caso que funcione como sí lo hace *institución* para referirse a un hospital psiquiátrico.

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con fedorqui, pero viendo los comentarios del OP en cada respuesta (especialmente el de la respuesta de Rodrigo), esta puede ser la mejor respuesta. Creo que no busca tanto un eufemismo como una variante, y "**centro**" o "**instalación**" o "**institución**" pueden servir. Pueden ser increíblemente ambiguos pero emisor y receptor (o lector de la carta) deben entender el contexto y quedará claro a que se refieren. Claro, no se puede tener todo a la vez. O bien el contexto o bien el término tiene que explicar. Habrá que sumir que tenemos uno de los dos.

Comment: centro penitencial o centro carcelario pueden servir.

Answer (score 5):

Puedes probar con `penitenciario` o `centro penitenciario`. Del [DRAE "penitenciaría"](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=wUru9WAqZDXX2mnb58KE)

> Establecimiento penitenciario en que sufren condenas los penados, sujetos a un régimen que, haciéndoles expiar sus delitos, va orientado a su enmienda y mejora.

O podrías in incluso con `Centros de readaptación (o reinserción) social`, `correccional` o `Institución correccional` (aunque estas dos últimas suenan más a centro de menores que a prisión de adultos.

Comment: ¿Puedo usar *correccional* como sustantivo?

Comment: Sí, [mira aquí](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=OppCRMCUnDXX2A8r6zRX)

Comment: Correccional es muchas veces entendido como una cárcel para adolescentes y niños. Centro de readaptación me parece un eufemismo perfecto.

Comment: *Centro de readaptación* me ofendería si yo estuviera encarcelada.  Lo bonito de *facility* es que se puede usar en muchísimos contextos que no tienen nada que ver con la cárcel.

Answer (score 5):

Los siguientes son de uso habitual en Chile:

> Centro de detención
>
> Centro de cumplimiento penitenciario
>
> Centro de reinserción social

Y los siguientes no creo que "suavicen" la carga negativa de la palabra, pero se usan para evitar decirla directamente:

> Penitenciaría
>
> Reclusorio
>
> Penal

Comment: Gracias, pero no son eufemismos.  No suavizan la dura realidad de vivir en una cárcel.  En la carta que estoy traduciendo, quiero usar una palabra que por el contexto se entienda como cárcel, pero fuera de contexto podría ser otra cosa.

Answer (score 2):

### Podrían ser:

- Penal
- reformatorio
- correccional
- presidio
- penitenciaría

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia se usa un eufemismo para **carcel**:  *Modelar*,  esto en virtud a que la carcel mas grande de Bogota y Colombia es la Penitenciaria Central Modelo.  Entonces *le toco ir a modelar* es el eufemismo para decir que fue a la carcel.  Con certeza entre los malandros existen muchos,  pero dado que no conozco ni cohabito con este tipo de personas,  no los conozco.

Comment: Interesante, aunque el término no sería entendido fuera de Colombia, imagino. En España casi seguro que no.