# "a secas" o "a palo seco" para referirse a "solo"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones

Estaba leyendo [una respuesta de Gorpik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15014/1674) cuando, comentándola, pensé en la expresión **"a secas"**.

Con "a secas" nos referimos a "solamente":

> Me llamo Juan Palomo, pero puedes llamarme Juan a secas.

Y también usamos "a palo seco" para mencionar algo hecho (o normalmente bebido) solo.

> Juan se bebe el whisky a palo seco. ¡Ni siquiera le pone hielo!

Entonces me pregunto: ¿es este referirse a "seco" como algo "solo" algo idiomático? ¿cuál sería su origen? Y... ¿se usa en España a secas o en algún lugar más? : )

Comment: A secas también se usa en varias partes de latinoamérica. Pero se usa rara vez (sin que suene extraño).

Comment: Curioso, @Joze, gracias por el comentario. ¿Tiene algún registro asociado? Es decir, ¿se usa en por ejemplo ambiente más académico o vulgar o... ?

Comment: No... no hay registro, se puede usar en todas partes. Registro común. Puede ser formal o informal. No pienso que sería apropiado a un contexto académico (opinión personal) pero sí a un contexto profesional por ejemplo. O incluso entre amigos.

Comment: En Chile _a secas_ es muy frecuente. _A palo seco_ no lo había escuchado nunca.

Comment: *A palo seco* es una expresión que procede de la náutica. Navegar *a palo seco* significa hacerlo con las velas recogidas; es decir, sin nada en los palos (mástiles). Por tanto, supongo que la expresión *a secas* es anterior a esta.

Comment: @Gorpik este mismo origen menciona El País en su artículo [A ver quién traduce esto: 14 expresiones que solo entendemos los españoles](http://elpais.com/elpais/2016/05/03/icon/1462269209_967007.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La expresión **a secas** no es una rareza ni mucho menos. Está en el Quijote varias veces (cerca del año 1600). Este fragmento es del último capítulo:

> ...en tanto que don Quijote fue Alonso Quijano el Bueno, a secas, y en tanto que fue don Quijote de la Mancha, fue siempre de apacible condición y de agradable trato...

Lo más atrás que pude encontrarlo con un "googleo" simple es en un [manual de veterinaria de 1507](https://books.google.cl/books?id=EFLUGIDRsgIC&pg=PT43&dq=a%20secas&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=a%20secas&f=false):

> ...no deve dar el cavallero las espuelas mucho a secas en el principio que le haze perder el coraçon...

Mi teoría es que la expresión (un *adverbio*, creo) no proviene del latín *siccare*, que significa "secar", sino de *secare* que significa **"cortar"**, palabra de la que derivan *segar* y *sector*. De hecho si escribes "ad secas" en el traductor de Google de latín a español, te propone "para cortar". Siguiendo esta idea, el significado original de *a secas* estaría más cerca de "tajante", o "cortante" que de otros posibles sentidos metafóricos relativos a la "sequedad".

Comment: Una vez más (y van...), gracias por la interesante investigación.

Comment: Aunque la palabra *secar* ya no tiene en castellano el sentido de *cortar*, sí nos han llegado otras palabras relacionadas como *secante* o *intersecar*. Tu teoría me parece coherente y tiene todos los visos de ser cierta.